# ANDROID : deserialise json string from file to class object

Tags: java, android, json, file, deserialization

I am trying to figure out how to save my Todo List in a file and then obtain it when I reopen the application. So far, my entries are saving to file correctly as a string, but I don't know how to get them back out of the string and display on screen. I guess I have to deserialize it, but I don't know how that works and would really appreciate some help.

This is a sample of my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Entry> mEntries;
String json;
Gson gson;
File dir, saveLocation;
FileWriter file1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gson = new Gson();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(dir,"storage.json")));
        Entry e = gson.fromJson(br, Entry.class); 
      //I'm stuck here, Don't know how to proceed

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    json = gson.toJson(mEntries);
    Log.d("jsondata", json);
    try {
        dir = getFilesDir();
        saveLocation = new File(dir,"storage.json");
        file1 = new FileWriter(saveLocation);
        file1.write(json);
        file1.flush();
        file1.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Entry.java**

```
public class Entry {
String S;
boolean b;

public Entry(String S, boolean b) {
    this.S = S;
    this.b = b;
}
//Getter and Setter methods
```

A sample of the json saved in the file:

[{"S":"hello there","b":false},{"S":"task1","b":true},{"S":"task2","b":false}]

// Here S is the task to do and b is whether it is done or not

Comment: Show us your json

Comment: Added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

```
Entry e = gson.fromJson(br, Entry.class);
```

This line of code has already deserialized the string.

Comment: but how? If I do this how will I get all the entries? and how do I display it on the screen?

Comment: ArrayList<Entry> tmp = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList.class);
or
ArrayList<Entry> tmp = gson.fromJson(json, Entry[].class);

Comment: I am getting an error like so : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference at calpoly.edu.challenge4.MyAdapter.getItemCount(MyAdapter.java:54)

Answer (score 0):

since your file contain Json array, you should parse it into array of `Entry` rather than single instance of `Entry`, for example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(dir,"storage.json")));
Entry[] entries = gson.fromJson(br, Entry[].class);
```